# Singapore visa-free entry: staying longer than duration indicated on entry slip?

Tags: us-citizens, singapore, visa-free-entry

My entry slip into Singapore had a field for the length of my stay. I wrote 35 days, but, after enjoying the country, I want to stay an extra month. As an American-citizen tourist, I can enter Singapore visa-free for up to 90 days.

Are there any consequences of staying longer than the duration I wrote on my entry slip? For example, do I need to take any action to amend my intended duration of stay? Is there a chance of problems at exit immigration or when I enter the country in the future?

Comment: As much as I love Singapore, I really don't see how you could find it interesting enough to want to spend 2 months there!  Each to their own I suppose!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't matter what you wrote on the form - what matters is what was put in your passport.

If you check the stamp you got at entry it will say how long you are allowed stay in the country.  For example, a few weeks ago I entered Singapore intending to stay for 1 night, so I put either 1 or 2 days on the form (I don't recall which), however on my passport the stamp says :

PERMITTED TO STAY IN SINGAPORE FOR NINETY DAYS FOR SOCIAL VISIT ONLY FROM DATE SHOWN ABOVE.

Thus I could have extended my 1 night stay up to 90 days without any repercussions.

The one catch with this is that Singapore entry stamps have a habit of smudging when stamped, so you may not actually be able to read the text referenced above, but as an American citizen you can pretty much guarantee that you'll have a standard "visit pass" that is valid for 90 days from entry.

Comment: +1, this is correct.  It's also worth noting that you do *not* want to exceed the permitted time stamped in your passport: Singapore has heavy fines and bans for overstayers, escalating to physical punishment (judicial caning) if you overstay by more than 90 days!